# Can only scrape the base price with requests html

Tags: python-requests-html

In the product price listed below, I fail to scrape the prices of the more expensive options.
Strangely, I can save a direct URL link and see the correct price when the page loads. However, when I scrape the same link with requests-html, I only get the base price of the base product.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = 'https://www.staegerag.ch/shop/index.php?id_product=321&controller=product&search_query=level&results=2#/273-farbe-gold_tone_light_oak/233-sprachsteuerung-nein'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
print(r.html.find('span[id="our_price_display"]', first=True).text)
```

Results in 1'399.00 CHF instead of 1'699.00 CHF

Answer (score 0):

After various google searches, i came across a simple solution. since i'm still a relatively new kid on the programming block, i didn't notice that my code didn't call chromium at all. my price to be scrapped is in java. I just had to render the page via: `r.html.render()` in chromium.

solution:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = 'https://www.staegerag.ch/shop/index.php? 
id_product=321&controller=product&search_query=level&results=2#/273-farbe- 
gold_tone_light_oak/233-sprachsteuerung-nein'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
print(r.html.find('span[id="our_price_display"]', first=True).text)
```